# How can I map an object type into an extension of itself

Tags: typescript

I want to extend my object:

```
interface MyObject {
  a: string;
}
```

with additional data, like:

```
type MyObjectExtended = MyObject & { b: number}
```

And I have myObj property and a function to retrieve MyObject:

```
private myObj: MyObjectExtended;

private getMyObject(): Observable<MyObject> {
  return of({a: 'a'});
}
```

Now I can do something like:

```
this.getMyObject().subscribe(myObj => {
  const myObjExtended = myObj as MyObjectExtended;
  myObjExtended.b = 1;
  return this.myObj = myObjExtended;
});
```

but it seems odd to me that I have to cast myObj that comes inside the observable.
I would prefer to do something like:

```
this.getMyObject().subscribe(myObj => this.myObj = myObj & {b:1});
```

Is there a way to it, to map it directly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to get the behavior you're looking for.  `Object.assign(obj, ...rest)` will copy all the properties from the list of `rest` parameters into the `obj` object, and TypeScript's type signature for `Object.assign()` in the [standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.5/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L286) returns an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of all the arguments.  So the following should behave as you'd like:

```
    this.getMyObject().subscribe(myObj => {            
        return this.myObj = Object.assign(myObj, { b: 1 });
    });
```

Or, more tersely:

```
    this.getMyObject().subscribe(myObj =>
        this.myObj = Object.assign(myObj, { b: 1 })
    );
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!